# Jquery selecting checkbix and building a url to be send to database

Tags: jquery, ajax

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xytvg

Every checkbox has id and value, for instance if I checked the qualified checkbox or unqualified checkbox.

I want disabled that checkbox depend on which one was clicked and I want this to be done on success call back function.

Here is my code down below:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function( e ){

    var preview = $("#preview").html('');

    // ** just a loader a gif image
    preview .html('<img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

    // ** this is the value of the checkbox
    var input = $(this).val();

    // ** here i am pulling the id value
    var id    = $(this).attr('id'); 


   $.ajax({
       // here i am trying to build url to be send to the action.php
       // i will get the id and the value depends on which checkbox was clicked 
       // action.php?id=1&value=2

       url: 'action.php?id='+id+'&value='+input, 
       type: "POST",
       success: function( response )
      {
           // here i want to figure out which checkbox was clicked and disabled it
      }
  });

  e.preventDefault();

});



<div id="preview"></div><!--loader gif-->

<p>
   USA
   <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="2" />Qualified OR 
   <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="3" /> Unqualifed
</p>

<p>
   UK 
   <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" />Qualified OR 
   <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="3" /> Unqualifed
</p>

<p>
   EGY 
   <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="2" />Qualified OR 
   <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" /> Unqualifed
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the checkbox to a variable in your click handler like this:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function( e ) {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    // rest of click handler code
```

Then in the success callback you can disable it like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'action.php?id='+id+'&value='+input, 
   type: "POST",
   success: function( response )
   {
       $checkbox.attr('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks clav for replaying , but where this should go, inside the success call back function

Comment: Yes, assign the `$checkbox` var in the click handler then disable the checkbox in the success callback. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, man, god bless you bro, i got that. you see, i am just learning jQuery , i have been just a week learning it, so i don't have the experience to make things solved quickly . thank you i really appreciated .

Comment: is there a better way to build url not like this one above rather than this ugly 'action.php?id='+id+'&value='+input, i just figured it out but i dont know how to make things better

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function( e ){
  // You just need to localize the var here :)
  var $this = $(this);
  var preview = $("#preview").html('');

  preview.html('<img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

  var input = $(this).val();

  var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'action.php?id='+id+'&value='+input, 
    type: "POST",
    success: function (response) {
      // We added the localized var up above so now it's accessible to this scope :)
      $this.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
```